# Open all plus buttons on page using Selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Please someone help me. I have been working on this for more than a week with no luck!I want to click and open multiple plus buttons and print out their content if there is the word "cardiovascular" in it, like the picture, below.
[image]

Here is the code that I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path=r"G:\My Drive\chrome_driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView')
sidebar = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div")
i=1
for i in range(16):  # since I have 16 div(s)
   sidebar.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[i]")       
   element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div").find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[i]").find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-scope']/span")
   element.click()
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[i]"}
```

I have also put 2 screen shots of the html page. One, shows all div(s), the other one shows one of the div(s) expanded.
Any help is appreciated!  [image][image]

Comment: Are you testing the website, or scraping the data? Depending on that will change how I answer this and the techniques I will use.

Comment: Hi @PixelEinstein, scraping the data.

Comment: @PixelEinstein, I need to iterate through the nodes, and if I see the word "cardiovascular" in any nodes, I need to extract the data that falls under that node! Even if the nodes included in the content have more plus buttons, I should open them all till the end and extract that information and put them in the Json format! But I was stuck at the first step!

Comment: @PixelEinstein any chance to look at the code? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation to the code:

```
i = 0
while True:
  # locate all elements
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@ng-if = 'node.HasChildren']/i[@ng-click='getTreeChildren(node)']")
  if len(elements) > i:
      elements[i].click() # click on the i-th element in the list
      i += 1 # increment i
      time.sleep(0.5) # wait until list will be updated
      continue
  break
```

you create a infinte loop, every time locate all elements to expand. Take the i-th element and click to expand. Wait until the dropdown will download(you can set another value in `wait`). Then you will execute `continue` statement to start `loop` from beginning. And this will be executed until the `list size` of located elements is bigger then `i`. Then you will reach `break` statement to `break` the `loop`. After this you can scrap the data.

Now you have all data visible on the page and you can locate all elements you need. I assume you want the spans(like `<span ng-if="!node.strong" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Blood-Air Barrier [A07.025]</span>`) text:

```
# spans is the list of all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of the current node and the current node itself
spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Cardiovascular')]/parent::*/parent::*/descendant-or-self::node()/a/span")
```

if you don't want the node self in the list, you can do like this:

```
# spans is the list of all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of the current node without current node itself
spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Cardiovascular')]/parent::*/parent::*/descendant::node()/a/span")
```

And finally you can for example prin the text of all elements like this:

```
for span in spans
  print span.text
```

The template:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView')
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait until page will be loaded

i = 0
while True:
  # locate all elements
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@ng-if = 'node.HasChildren']/i[@ng-click='getTreeChildren(node)']")
  if len(elements) > i:
      elements[i].click() # click on the i-th element in the list
      i += 1 # increment i
      time.sleep(0.5) # wait until list will be updated
      continue
  break


spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Cardiovascular')]/parent::*/parent::*/descendant-or-self::node()/a/span")
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
Blood-Air Barrier [A07.025]
Blood-Aqueous Barrier [A07.030]
Blood-Brain Barrier [A07.035]
...
```

EDIT:

for quick check you can use this template (it will expand only few nodes, just for test propose):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView')
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait until page will be loaded

i = 0
while i < 9:
  # locate all elements
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@ng-if = 'node.HasChildren']/i[@ng-click='getTreeChildren(node)']")
  if len(elements) > i:
      if i == 0:
          elements[i].click()
          i += 6
      elements[i].click() # click on the i-th element in the list
      i += 1 # increment i
      time.sleep(0.5) # wait until list will be updated
      continue
  break


spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'Cardiovascular')]/parent::*/parent::*/descendant-or-self::node()/a/span")
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
Cardiovascular System [A07]
Blood-Air Barrier [A07.025]
Blood-Aqueous Barrier [A07.030]
Blood-Brain Barrier [A07.035]
Blood-Nerve Barrier [A07.037]
Blood-Retinal Barrier [A07.040]
Blood-Testis Barrier [A07.045]
Blood Vessels [A07.231]
Adventitia [A07.231.057]
Arteries [A07.231.114]
Microvessels [A07.231.461]
Retinal Vessels [A07.231.611]
Tunica Intima [A07.231.700]
Tunica Media [A07.231.733]
Vasa Nervorum [A07.231.765]
Vasa Vasorum [A07.231.836]
Veins [A07.231.908]
Glomerular Filtration Barrier [A07.500]
Heart [A07.541]
```

More information about `xPath` axes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

ADD:

Since the node list on the website is very big(I din't know it), I have added a light version of the code above. Here is almost the same logic as already was. The difference is in following: firstly will be expanded the 16 main nodes, then will be located the node, which we searching and then will be expanded all only its children. It is much more quicker to get the result, but if search node is not on the "first" level, then will be nothing found. It is possible to go "deeper" and search on second, third etc. levels, but it will be complicated to implement. At least the logic how to deal with this problem I think is clear. PS the code above is also workable, but it slows down, when many nodes are presented, so it takes more time in `time.sleep()`.

Note: you have to specify the full word to make sure, that you will get only one node by search string. For example for `Cardiovascular` there are two nodes: `Cardiovascular System [A07]` and `Cardiovascular Diseases [C14]`. And the program will not expand all nodes for `Cardiovascular Diseases [C14]`. If you want to expand the second node either, you have to slightly change the code below. For `Cardiovascular System` will be only one node.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView')
driver.implicitly_wait(1) # wait until page will be loaded

search_word = "Cardiovascular System"
elements_xpath = "//span[@ng-if = 'node.HasChildren']/i[@ng-click='getTreeChildren(node)']"
spans_xpath = "//span[contains(., '" + search_word + "')]/parent::*/parent::*/descendant-or-self::node()/a/span"
link_xpath = "//span[@class = 'ng-binding ng-scope']"


# expand all nodes first level
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(elements_xpath)
for element in elements:
    element.click()
    time.sleep(0.3)

# search for span position
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(link_xpath)
i = 0
for element in elements:
    if search_word in element.text:
        break
    i += 1

# i is the position where the 'Cardiovascular' was found
# now is time to expand all child nodes at i position
end = i + 1
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'ng-scope']")
old_length = len(elements)

while i < end:
    elements[i].click()
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.3)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'ng-scope']")
    end = end + len(elements) - old_length
    old_length = len(elements)

# all child nodes are expanded
# time to collect information
spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(spans_xpath)
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Comment: I applied the code, but still does not open the plus buttons! @Andrei Suvorkov

Comment: Dod you also changed `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div").find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[i]").find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-scope']/span")`?

Comment: @ Andrei Suvorkov, yes I did. I run the program without any error but it does not open the plus buttons.

Comment: I have added `EDIT` block, please have a look an follow the instruction in it. This should work.

Comment: I truly appreciate you taking your time to help me. Here is the error that I get: Message: unknown error: Element <i class="fa fa-plus-circle treeCollapseExpand fakeLink ng-hide" id="plus_Anatomy" ng-show="!node.children || node.children.length==0" ng-click="getTreeChildren(node)"></i> is not clickable at point (6, 6). Other element would receive the click: <img src="/public/img/NIHLogo.png" alt="NIH Logo">     and when I changed it to only consider span tag, it stuck on the first node "Anatomy"    @Andrei Suvorkov

Comment: I'm sorry, the code had some small issues. I have fixed them, added the full code to execute and short DEMO code to quick test. Thank you for interesting challenge ))

Comment: THANKS A LOT, @Andrei Suvorkov. But using the template, the code never stops! it just continue looping from A to Z without printing anything. Any solution for this, please?

Comment: In `ADD` section you will find modificated and quicker code to do the job. In the first code template `the code never stops!` is not the case, it will stop, but it will take long time(too many subnodes).

Comment: I just wanted to appreciate you for taking your time to help me out on this.